# Common methods in parent class

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design

Imagine this simple PHP class:

```
<?php
class MyParent
{
    // this is our common method, we don't use this method anywhere in parent class
    // but we may or may not use this method in some child classes.
    protected function helperMethod()
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

How is it to have methods like top one in our classes? Is this OOP?
I don't have good feeling about this, cause if we don't use these methods in our child classes they will be completely useless and they can confuse people. please tell me your idea.

Another example:

```
abstract class Package
{
    // We will never use this method in this class
    protected function getAConfigParam()
    {
        ConfigHolder->getParam('myconfig');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        [...]
        this->registerPackage();
        [...]
    }

    abstract public function registerPackage();
}

class PackageForCli extends Package
{
    public function registerPackage()
    {
        // We will use getAConfigParam method here.
    }
}

class PackageForWeb extends Package
{
    public function registerPackage()
    {
        // We will use getAConfigParam method here.
    }
}
```

In the top example we have also access to the ConfigHolder in child classes, but which one should we use? getAConfigParam method or ConfigHolder?

Comment: One makes classes that are "children" of a "parent" class for a reason. What's your reason? Looks like your "children" classes shouldn't have that parent after all.

Comment: It's totally code smell. The function is going to be better placed in a utility-like class. As soon as it's pure and stateless.

Comment: _"we don't use this method anywhere in parent class"_ sometimes a class exposes a method that it itself doesn't use, but "clients" will use.

Comment: I thin that if you don't put a real name for "MyParent" and for "helperMethod", an useful question will be impossible. Only with context can we say if something is wrong.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Yes, but in my case sometimes method gets completely useless, I don't in this situation, this is best design or not...

Comment: As "MyParent" and "helperMethod" say nothing about the context, only you know what the situation is.

Comment: @Laiv We can use utility trait, but it doesn't work always, for example imagine a "common method" that you are using for getting a config param.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova I don't think we really need context, the situation is obvious and we always impact to methods like this one in OOP, you think what is the best way to deal with these methods?

Comment: Method that you heavly coupled to the parent because it was a centric component in your design maybe? Could not the Configuration be accessed throught the proper ConfigurationHolder or Configuration component throught DI? And why the access to the method is eventual?. It points to the fact that is eventually important and eventually relevant to your hierarchy of components.

Comment: @Laiv ofcourse it can be accessed through ConfigurationHolder but there is an other problem here, and it is code duplication, and changing the IP of config param will be cost to edit all children. I don't know this is OK in OOP or not.

Comment: Here your answer. You are using inheritance for DRY. That's not the aim beneath inheritance. These methods belongs to another component. Usually OOP is not exempt of complexity. We have to deal with that.

Comment: @Laiv so what should I do? forget about code duplication and just call ConfigurationHolder each time I need in child classes? if code duplication is ok here, It seems good for me.

Comment: Do inject the component into those children that need it. If the whole hierarchy systematically need the holder, then move the injection to the parent.

Comment: @Laiv but in some cases my parent class is an abstract and method is "protected" or "private". I have only to choices here:
1: make the method "protected" and call it in child classes.
2: make the method "private" and call the ConfigurationHolder in child classes.

Comment: Without more context we can not provide you with acurate answers. Consider typing a real parent and children class instead of the actual example.

Comment: @Laiv I did, plz take a look at the question again.

Comment: What about `this->registerPackage(gerAConfigParam());` however It doesn't solve the Tulains question: Do children classes need the parent for something else? If you use inheritance for DRY, then you are probably missing a cross-cutting concept.

Comment: @Laiv It will be much better, but the child class can forget about our param and just use ConfigHolder for getting his param, is this OK?

Comment: Classes don't forget to do things, developers do. Nothing can stop a developer from injecting the ConfigurationHolder wherever he want.

Comment: @Laiv Ok, thank you for your help, I will do like this, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm right, your doing something called  *[template method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)*. It's a OOP design pattern. So far so good.

> In the template method of this design pattern, one or more algorithm
>   steps can be overridden by subclasses to allow differing behaviors
>   while ensuring that the overarching algorithm is still followed

What we miss in your case is if *the configuration* is required to ensure that the overarching *registration* process  is follwed.

If it is required, then you have to inject it into the template method.

```
abstract class Package
{

    public function register()
    {
        [...]
        this->registerPackage(ConfigHolder->getParam('myconfig'));
        [...]
    }

    abstract public function registerPackage(ConfigParam cfgParam);
}

class PackageForCli extends Package
{
    public function registerPackage(ConfigParam cfgParam)
    {
        // We will use getAConfigParam method here.
    }
}

class PackageForWeb extends Package
{
    public function registerPackage(ConfigParam cfgParam)
    {
        // We will use getAConfigParam method here.
    }
}
```

Now, no common method in the super class is need it. At least not the one we are talking about.

The above solution, wont stop a developer from doing this:

```
   class PackageForMobile extends Package
    {
        public function registerPackage(ConfigParam cfgParam)
        {
            //ignoring ConfigParam
            ConfigHolder->getParam('myconfig');
        }
    }
```

Or totally ignore the ConfigParam whether you deem it necessary or not.

If you find the child classes to be ignoring the ConfigParam systematically, then remove the access to the param. [YAGNI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

If you find the child classes eventually accessing to the ConfigParam, consider allowing them to get access to it via DI and remove the ConfigParam from the template. [YAGNI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) again. Just one more consideration, inject the ConfigParam into the children instead of calling the the configHolder directly. It's easier to unit test with DI.

You didn't say if `getAConfigurationParam()` is required by the children's consumers. If consumers do need access to the ConfigParam, then the method is still necessary. That depends on your needs and requirements. But it should not affect the *overarching registration process*.

Comment: If by consumers you mean users outside of the class, I have to say no, this method is only necessary for child classes this is why it is protected.

Comment: Then you know what to do ;-).